# nespresso capsule - type with least tannin

Tags: nespresso

I am sensitive to tannin but a big fan of coffee so I'm trying to find a variety that will produce the least tannin in my regular dose. I reckon I should go with espresso as it has the lowest extraction time, and a light roast like the volluto nespresso capsules. Does that seem reasonable? Any other ideas? I'd like to make an informed decision. Thanks!